# PostgreSQL Performance - Checking if a row exist in a function returning boolean

Tags: performance, postgresql

I'm trying to make a function in PostgreSQL which returns `true` or `false` if a row exist. It's very easy in SQL, and performance is good:

```
SELECT exists (SELECT 1
 FROM Users u
 WHERE u.id = $1)
```

But when I try to  create a function with this code, the performance is terrible:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userExist(userId integer) 
RETURNS boolean AS $$ 
 SELECT exists (SELECT 1
     FROM User u
     WHERE u.id = $1);
 $$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

I call this function like that :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM userExist(1);
```

Seems that the problem is the same as a previous question I ask ( [PostgreSQL Performance - SELECT vs Stored function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935653/postgresql-performance-select-vs-stored-function) ), but the answer i get last time doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: You have a scalar function which returns a single value. Don't put that in the `from` clause, use `select userexist(1);`

Comment: Ok, otherwise performance are exactly the same with or without the `from`